# How to undo the changes, if any process define in the JAVA web service fails?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, resteasy, java

I am working on the JAVA web application. In that I am using JAVA Web Services at server side and Angular JS at client side. The main problem is that say if I am uploading image, the code written for that image upload at server side fails, then how to revert the changes made by the code, if that api fails?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "changes made by the code". Do you mean database or other kind of resources?

But my suggestion would be to have a look at using [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: Yes exactly database and regarding images